# Обход блокировок РКН на роутере?

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизация

Имеем роутер с `opkg` и запущенным тором, благодаря чему можно перенаправить `tcp` трафик, например, с рутрекера в тор:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -d rutracker.org -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

**Вопрос**: как с минимальными усилиями парсить весь список запрещенных сайтов и добавлять правила в `iptables` на роутере?

PS. `ipset` какой-то урезанный, с ним ничего не получилось.

Comment: Вы реестр запрещенных сайтов видели ? На данный момент в нем 13612 доменов с указанными 17955 уникальными IP-адресами. Вам нужно делать минимум трехуровневую систему обычных правил, что бы маршрутизатор не захлебнулся. В одной цепочке iptables делать более 500 записей крайне нежелательно. Вот как раз ipset рулит. И кстати задавать в правиле iptables _ИМЯ_ домена так же нельзя, он реально добавит правило только на 1 ip адрес, а у рутрекера их несколько и они часто меняются (иногда несколько раз в день !!!)

Comment: @Mike тогда как быть с ipset? Он оочень сильно урезан. Роутер не должен захлебнуться - два ARM ядра, как-никак.
P.S. Урезан настолько, что не понимает "restore"

Comment: Восьмиядерный i7 захлебывается на 100-200 МБит потоке если в цепочке более 1000 правил. В linux работой iptables по пакетам с одной сетевухи работает только одно ядро. Так что: 1. из реестра брать тупо список ip. 2. Если провайдер режет не только по списку но и имени, резолвить имена доменов и добавлять в список. 3. По списку строить разветвленную систему правил, типа все ip 1.0.0.0/8 отправляем в цепочку 1, там выделаем более мелкую подсеть 1.1.0.0/16 в цепочку 1-1 из в ней если на нее пришлось мало ip пишем их сами, если много - бьем на более мелкие подсети